# Setting counter for collision

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Currently I have a game that when you click on the canvas and a piece of food will be draw on it. And then the fish sprite will move towards the food to eat it.

This is the function to let the fish to move towards to the food:

```
Fish.prototype.eatFood = function() {
    var foodX, foodY;
    var halfWidth = this.frameWidth * this.frameScale / 2;
    var halfHeight = this.frameHeight * this.frameScale / 2;
    // Loop backward because we are removing elements.
    for (var i = foodArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        foodX = foodArray[i].x + foodWidth / 2;
        foodY = foodArray[i].y + foodHeight / 2;
        if (foodX > this.xPos - halfWidth &&
            foodX < this.xPos + halfWidth &&
            foodY > this.yPos - halfHeight&&
            foodY < this.yPos + halfHeight)
        {
            foodArray.splice(i, 1); //Clearing away food after both of it collide
        }
    }
};
```

How can i set a counter, so everytime when the fish eats the food the counter will increase.

Comment: have you tried keeping a global variable and increasing it after `foodArray.splice(i, 1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help: Create a variable at the beginning of the script (Global) and initialize it to `0`. Then whenever the food is disappearing, that is in here : `{
            foodArray.splice(i, 1); //Clearing away food after both of it collide
        }`

increase the variable. like this:

```
   ` {
        foodArray.splice(i, 1); //Clearing away food after both of it collide
        foodCount++;
    } `
```

That way, it will increase every time the fish eats food.

Comment: `document.getElementById("foodCount").innerHTML = foodCount;`
add the above line after the `foodCount++`

Comment: Add this line inside the main Fish(blah, blah, blah...) : `this.foodCount = 0;` and then change our previous edit to `this.foodCount++;
            document.getElementById("foodCount").innerHTML = this.foodCount;
            /* whenever a fish eats food, that fish's count is displayed */`

Comment: As for the food counter display, i just add more `<p id="foodCount"></p>` at my html file for the multiple counter display or how should i do it?

Comment: ids cannot be the same for more than one elements. use an array or something for saving the scores and then display it at a time. I suggest you go through javascript basics first, and then procceed. codecademy has a very good cource in it